# Fluent Nhibernate Order-By on Collection

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

If I have a collection mapped in Fluent NHibernate and I want to apply an order to that collection how do I do that?

Eg:

```
HasMany(x => x.PastDates)
            .AsBag().Cascade
            .SaveUpdate()
            .KeyColumnNames.Add("EventId")
            .Where(e => e.DateFrom < DateTime.Now.Date)
            .Inverse();
```

I'm looking for the equivalent of the order-by attribute in HBM files.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the "order-by" attribute is not in the FluentNHibernate API. I don't see an [issue](http://fluentnhibernate.org/issues) for it so this may be a conscious omission. You should be able to add it using SetAttribute but [this user](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/718d1daebc830597/17e44d0efb7a63dd?lnk=gst&q=%22order-by%22#17e44d0efb7a63dd) was unable to get it to work.

```
HasMany(x => x.PastDates)
        .AsBag().Cascade
        .SaveUpdate()
        .KeyColumnNames.Add("EventId")
        .Where(e => e.DateFrom < DateTime.Now.Date)
        .Inverse()
        .SetAttribute("order-by", "column_name");
```

Be aware that setting order-by [may change the collection type](https://www.hibernate.org/359.html) that NHibernate uses; however this does not apply for bags.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ill give that a try. Through posting this I spotted a glaring error also "< DateTime.Now.Date" really needs to be getDate().

Comment: This not a deliberate omission, FYI :)

Comment: Is there any way to sort in descending order this way?

Comment: @JC: Yes. The order-by attribute has the syntax "column_name asc|desc", so it's possible. Fluent NH has added OrderBy and I expect that it works the same. See http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-6/1nr4enxv3dpeq/9#6%282E%292%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Mapping_a_Collection

Comment: Couldn't you also map the collection as a list instead of a bag - being that a list is an ordered collection? eg ...AsList(_=>_.Column("EventId")

Answer (score 24):

Fluent NHibernate now has an OrderBy method which you can use:

```
HasMany(x => x.PastDates)
        .AsBag().Cascade
        .SaveUpdate()
        .KeyColumnNames.Add("EventId")
        .Where(e => e.DateFrom < DateTime.Now.Date)
        .Inverse()
        .OrderBy("ColumnName DESC");
```

Comment: I presume this is actually the name of the mapped attribute rather than the underlying column? either way it's a shame it isn't more consistent with Criterion.Order